# How can I use an HTTP Get request to only get a specific attribute within an object in an Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, get

Pretty much a newb here, So I'll try to explain what I'm doing as best as I can. I am trying to build a form with a select dropdown. The select's options are populated through an HTTP GET request that I fetch from my existing database of posts. All of the posts have a name attribute within an object inside the array. So I do not need all the information about the post, just the name attribute. How would I go about doing this, so that I can specifically get the name attribute and display it when I click the dropdown? the following is what I have so far... but it's still generic.

```js
export function getClients() {
  return http.get("/clients");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoint will give you what it gives you.  If you REALLY needed to and you have access to that code, you could change it or add a new endpoint to only return the things you need, `name` in this case.

However, this is not necessary.  It is very common for an endpoint to return more data than you need and it is usually the job of the front-end to pick out the values needed.

For example, if we had a list of items that came from the API, something like this:

```
 [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Rick Sanchez",
      "status": "Alive",
      "species": "Human",
      "type": "",
      "gender": "Male",
      "origin": {
        "name": "Earth (C-137)",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"
      },
      "location": {
        "name": "Earth (Replacement Dimension)",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"
      },
      "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg",
      "episode": [
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/3",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/4",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/5",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/7",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/8",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/9",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/11",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/12",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/13",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/14",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/15",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/16",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/17",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/18",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/19",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/20",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/21",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/23",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/24",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/25",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/26",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/27",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/29",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/30",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/31"
      ],
      "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1",
      "created": "2017-11-04T18:48:46.250Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Morty Smith",
      "status": "Alive",
      "species": "Human",
      "type": "",
      "gender": "Male",
      "origin": {
        "name": "Earth (C-137)",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"
      },
      "location": {
        "name": "Earth (Replacement Dimension)",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"
      },
      "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/2.jpeg",
      "episode": [
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/3",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/4",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/5",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/7",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/8",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/9",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/11",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/12",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/13",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/14",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/15",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/16",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/17",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/18",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/19",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/20",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/21",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/23",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/24",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/25",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/26",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/27",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/29",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/30",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/31"
      ],
      "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2",
      "created": "2017-11-04T18:50:21.651Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Summer Smith",
      "status": "Alive",
      "species": "Human",
      "type": "",
      "gender": "Female",
      "origin": {
        "name": "Earth (Replacement Dimension)",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"
      },
      "location": {
        "name": "Earth (Replacement Dimension)",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"
      },
      "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/3.jpeg",
      "episode": [
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/7",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/8",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/9",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/11",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/12",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/14",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/15",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/16",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/17",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/18",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/19",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/20",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/21",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/23",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/24",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/25",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/26",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/27",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/29",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/30",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/31"
      ],
      "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/3",
      "created": "2017-11-04T19:09:56.428Z"
    }
  ]
```

And we wanted to create a dropdown of character names out of it, we could do the following:

```
// react
// characters here is the list above
// Here, I take the list of characters (an array) and use map to return an array of `options` that display the name of each character in the array `characters`.

<select>
   {characters.map((character, index) => (
      <option key={index}>{character.name}</option>
   ))}
</select>
```

[Here is a full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-surf-num6u?file=/src/App.js:649-789) that includes code for fetching from an API

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I ended up mapping it to a new array and passing that as the option field for the select. It's working as expected now :3